# Operator & in ruby

Tags: ruby

There is a code in ruby

```
Dir.glob("my_folder/*.rb").each { |r| require_relative r}
```

I almost understand but I want to be sure why is the code below not working

```
Dir.glob("my_folder/*.rb").each(&:require_relative)
```

due to error of `NoMethodError: private method require_relative' called for "my_folder/one.rb":String`

Is this because

`Dir.glob("controllers/*.rb").each(&:require_relative)`

is equal to

`Dir.glob("controllers/*.rb").each{ |r| r.require_relative }`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is equivalent to

```
 .each{ |r| r.require_relative}
```

& calls `to_proc` on an object, in this case, a symbol, and `Symbol` implements it and creates a new Proc, which does a call on the object.

Comment: As an addition you can also use `.each(&method(:require_relative))`.